# winapi GetAsyncKeyState() does not work as described?

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

According to [microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx), GetAsyncKeyState() supposedly

> Determines whether a key is up or down at the time the function is called

I've been building a UI automation library and the issue boils down to this

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

bool IsKeydownAsync(int key) {
    return GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000;
}

int main(){
    while (1) {
        if (IsKeydownAsync('A')) {
            cout << "triggered" << endl;
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}
```

So my understanding is that it should not matter if my application is in focus or not, the GetAsyncKeyState() should always return whether the physical keys are up or down at the time of being called.

I have tested this over various applications and for most time it behaves as it is described. However, in some games this behavior breaks and it no longer reports whether the key is up or down. `cout << "triggered" << endl` doesn't get called when the key is held.

Is there something I overlooked?

Comment: You pay attention to **Return value** and **Remarks** sections of documentation. `GetAsyncKeyState` is probably not the best choice for input handling or UI automation. You should use something else.

Comment: @VTT The return value and remarks section only mentioned that the LSB is not reliable, however I'm testing only the MSB to see if the key is down. I was thinking to use RAWINPUT but that will be my last resort as I'm not so familliar with it

Comment: @ShawnLi could you explicitely mention the games that break the behaviour? Did I understand correctly: you press the A key in notepad, then your program displays "triggered", but if you press the A key in one of the games you mention "triggered" is no longer displayed?

Comment: Games notoriously use raw input to read the keyboard, intercepting keystrokes before they are handled through the normal plumbing.  It is a very cheap anti-cheat approach that can only be cracked by tinkering with the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while since I worked with native input in Windows, but from experience the Windows API functions only report key-states that are also reported using the synchronzied Windows API functionality, which is to say the normal application message/event input.

Some older games use previous versions of DirectX and alternative ways to capture input, e.g. using a library called the XInput(2) that has been deprecated since Windows 8.1 / 10. While both polling and events/msgs were supported, the input was caught using the DirectX thread and handled entirely differently compared to the Windows API. The main reason for this is that the OS tries to cater to all manufacturers, where the DirectX API did not specificcally address that issue for input.

Comment: The first paragraph only applies to the synchronous [GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx) function, not `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState returns more 'associated interrupt-level state' information, but it still flows through the same OS virtual key layer. Strange as it may sound, this is still different then what the driver knows about your keyboard, which is what DirectInput / XInput are returning.

Comment: Really don't want to write drivers... but seems like this is the only option